# Reuse dateformat from fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using the fullcalendar plugin to display the weekview. Is it possible to reuse the dateformatter that fullcalendar uses to format dates in different elements? And how exactly would I have to do this?

Example:
display current date as ('short day name' 'monthnumber'/'day of month number') (="Thu 2/21") like in the weekview. but this in a div tag or something like that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - FullCalendar provides a utility function called `formatDate`. Check the docs for this - [formatDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/)

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: but how can I use this function outside of the calendar? like I said in the example given in my original post

Comment: Like this - `$.fullCalendar.formatDate( new Date(), 'ddd, M/d')`. Make sure to have the fullcalendar.js included in your page.

Comment: awesome! this was exactly what I was looking for and it saved me SO much time